# How easy is it to combine symbolic and numeric computation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

CS Beta people:

I have been doing some multiple integrals with a combination of symbolic and numerical integration (because symbolic answers have not always been possible).  I have been using Mathematica to do the symbolic integration, cut-and-pasting the results into Matlab, and then using quad or dblquad in Matlab.  I could probably do the whole thing in Mathematica, but I would like to develop my Matlab skills.  My question is, is there a convenient way to use Matlab's symbolic capabilities to do this more efficiently, without cut-and-pasting?

The only symbolic engine I have access to in Matlab is mupad (I don't have the Maple Toolbox, for example).  I would consult the Mathworks documentation, but I have found it deficient on several other questions, and I would like to hear from someone who has actually done it.

EDIT (March 5): Someone asked me to be more specific.  Here is part of what I'm doing.  I want to evaluate the triple integral

$$\int_1^{RmaxOverRmin} \int_1^{r_2}\int_0^{r_2-r_1}\frac{r_1^3 t^2}{r_2^3}\exp(-\frac{t^2}{4 dOverRmin^2})\,dt\,dr_1\,dr_2.$$

Mathematica can't do it symbolically, so it is probably impossible.  Mathematica can do the inner double integral symbolically.  So I did it, cut-and-pasted the results into a Matlab function file, and used Matlab's "quad" to integrate the result as $r_2$ went from $1$ to $RmaxOverRmin$.

Stefan (STack Exchange FAN)

Comment: Yes, I've done this sort of thing exactly.  Your problem is still a bit too general, if you'd like a specific answer (instead of a comment), could you post a more specific problem, giving the details of the numerical integration you are trying to do?

Comment: In my experience if you need to do _anything_ symbolic, you're best off sticking with Mathematica. Matlab can probably do it, but it is atrocious.

Comment: If you are not tied to Matlab, you could check out the combination of [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org)/[SciPy](http://www.scipy.org) and [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org).

Comment: @Aron : I added to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use [mEngine](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/4821/). I have not worked with it, but I am pretty sure it will be a breeze to install and use. Not sure exactly how the expressions will be transferred though.

Otherwise you could just write the expressions into text files. Then you can run `f=sym(somestring);` to have MATLAB parse it into a symbolic object. Then just substitute using `subs()`.

Edit : Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510770/how-to-invoke-a-matlab-function-from-mathematica) answer.